# List Report in Report Builder 3 - Can it be side by side?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can  a list report in Report builder 3 be side by side instead of top to bottom and if so where can I make that change.

edit--- from what I have found on the net I have to do something along the lines off newspaper column, can some explain in layman terms how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely possible, but not something offered by default. First we need to understand what SSRS creates when you select a List, then do something similar at the column level instead of the row level.

When you create a List, this is actually a Tablix with one row, one column and one TextBox, with a Rectangle embedded in the TextBox. Since it's a Rectangle, you can then embed any element in the Rectangle in the required position to achieve a free-form list:

[image]

You can see there is one group created automatically, called Details. This has no group expression, which means it will just repeat for each row in the DataSet:

[image]

So a simple List looks something like this:

[image]

To achieve a side-by-side List, we need to change the underlying Tablix to have a similar group to Details, but in a column group.

To do this:

1. Delete the row group Details.
2. Add a new column group (name doesn't matter). When creating a group, you must select a column from your DataSet - just select any row here.
3. Remove the group expression from the new column group

[image]

Now we have an equivalent Details group at the column level. It should look something like this:

[image]

When run this is now a side-by-side List as required:

[image]

Comment: @wafw1971, you're welcome. It was an interesting question to test out; it's nice when things work the way you hope. A rare commodity when using SSRS.

Comment: Great Job! Is it possible to break to a new line after showing two records in case you have more than 2 ?